# What is the added cost of generalizing an eigensystem?

Tags: linear-algebra, performance, eigensystem

### Problem

Let's say I can write a model as the Hermitian eigensystem:
$$ A x = \lambda x $$
where $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ is Hermitian, or as the generalized Hermitian eigensystem:
$$ \tilde A \tilde x = \lambda \tilde B \tilde x $$
where $\tilde A, \tilde B \in \mathbb{C}^{\tilde n \times \tilde n}$ are Hermitian and $\tilde B$ is positive definite.
How much smaller must $\tilde n$ be than $n$ for the generalized model to be more efficient?

### Qualifications

I understand that there are many other factors that influence the answer.  A general intuition would be best, but, if added complexity is unavoidable, assume:

- Serial solver
- Direct solver
- $A,\tilde A, \tilde B$ are dense
- The $m$ eigen-pairs with lowest eigenvalues are desired, where $n / m \approx 10$
- $A$ and $\tilde A, \tilde B$ model the same system, so the relative differences in the $m$ eigen-pairs are small
- $\tilde B = I + \hat{B}$ where $\text{rank}(\hat{B}) = p$, and $p \approx 2 m = n/5$

Answers for a different set of qualifications might be useful to other readers as well.

Comment: Which eigenpairs do you want?  Does $\tilde B$ have structure (sparsity, a kernel, etc)?  How does the spectrum of the two formulations compare?  (This affects which algorithm will be used.)

Comment: @JedBrown low-eigenvalue eigen-pairs.  $\tilde B - I$ is not full rank, but it is not quite low rank and is dense.  The spectrum's should be almost the same.  Edited qualifications accordingly.

Comment: How concentrated is the spectrum of $A$ (or $\tilde B^{-1/2} \tilde A \tilde B^{-1/2}) near the origin?  Have you compared the cost of solving using a shift-and-invert spectral transform?  (Internal eigenvalues are hard, but extreme eigenvalues, even near zero, can often be found quickly without needing to invert.)

Comment: In my particular case, the spectrum is approximately linear, $\lambda_n \in [(n-1) \omega,(n+1)\omega] + E_o$, but allowing for some degeneracy and with somewhat arbitrary shift $E_o$ (positive or negative).  I will look into shift-and-invert.

Comment: This is the pretty nicely-separated scenario where a standard diagonal shift is likely sufficient.  You probably don't need shift-and-invert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a dense, direct solver, Golub and Van Loan (*Matrix Computations*, 3rd ed) report the following cost estimates for eigenvalues only:

- standard eigenproblem: $10n^3$ (p. 359).
- generalized eigenproblem: $30n^3$ (p. 385).

Costs are in flops (additions and multiplications cost $1$ each).

If you want eigenvectors as well, you have to compute the orthogonal matrix in the Schur decomposition (or either $Q$ or $Z$ in QZ, respectively) as well and then you can obtain them using inverse iteration. Costs are not explicitly reported in GVL, but my guess is the following (for $m$ eigenvectors out of $n$, I am assuming one step of inverse iteration ($n^2$) on the triangular matrix is enough, and then multiplication by the orthogonal matrix ($2n^2$)):

- standard eigenproblem: $25n^3 + 3n^2m$
- generalized eigenproblem: $46n^3+3n^2m$.

All these figures are approximate because they assume a "typical average" number of shifted QR/QZ steps.

If it's a sparse eigenproblem or it's larger than it fits in RAM, I doubt you can get realistical *a priori* estimates (but I am a dense guy, so I might be wrong).

Comment: Let me add that in practice, unless you write your own code for eigenvector extraction, standard methods will only compute either all ($m=n$) or no eigenvectors.